# Can I enable Intel HD Graphics in my Laptop BIOS with no display?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios, integrated-graphics

This is an odd request, but somehow after plugging in a j5 Create USB-to-HDMI splitter and installing their driver, my Radeon graphics card now shows up as disconnected in the Device Manager.  The Intel HD 4000 Graphics Display Adapter doesn't show up at all.  As a result, plugging an external monitor into the VGA or HDMI ports does nothing.

My only access is by remote desktop via TeamViewer, which obviously doesn't load until Windows does.  I've tried installing the drivers for Intel HD, but it has no effect, and I read that I need to have the integrated Display Adapter enabled in the BIOS first.

So... is there any way to modify BIOS settings if I don't have access to a hardwired display?

- Toshiba Satellite S870
- Windows 10
- 3rd Gen i7

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Updating the drivers of the graphics card will shut it off. I doubt whatever you did had any effect on the BIOS though. You'll probably get it back after reboot.

Comment: @ventsyv I've tried rebooting a couple dozen times at this point.  I read that holding the power button down with the laptop unplugged and battery out will reset the BIOS.  I didn't realize that's what it would do, but that was a suggested step on a Tom's Hardware page, so I wonder if I accidentally reset the BIOS setting for Integrated Graphics and shut of the Intel HD 4000 Display Adapter.